# Unified Sort of Items Within Multiple Column Groups Based on Collated Sort of Key Value Columns Within Each Group

Tags: excel, sorting, multiple-columns, data-processing

I have columnated data set where a single group of data in columns with a single key column, I have ***i*** data sets (groups), each spanning ***j*** columns, an each containing its own key value column.

I am processing this data with what I'd dub a **"co-sort"**, a complex sort / multi-group sort that sorts all groups by simultaneously consider all groups' key columns (or you could say, sorting on their collation).  This creates a final table where the data points in all groups are ordered in such a way so as to provide a cohesive cross-group ordering relative all groups' respective key columns.

As an example if we start with:

[image: individually sorted data sets]

The result after doing this process manually:

[image: co-sort in Excel, nicely formatted]

I know how to do this sort -- I've already been doing it manually.  I'm confident I know how to build from scratch a script to implement it and have outlined a code plan for a shell script to do so.

What I don't know -- and what my question is -- is there something already built to do this special sort (existing library / shell tool / etc.)?

It seems there likely would be as my sort isn't really that novel, and seems visually and perhaps mathematically to be likely an obvious data representation that would frequently be desired when dealing with this specific kind of data associated -- multiple groups sharing a common format sorted on some common field.

And yet, I haven't been able to find any such simple pre-built solution to perform this specialized search.  That said, I am hoping someone else knows of one.

To confirm the specifics of what that would entail, I'll subsequently describe in more detail the assumptions about the starting data and high level algorithm of the co-sort, with the above illustrations laid out in more detail as examples in each case. Finally, I'll close by laying out what I've tried & the coding plan if I implement myself.

That should give a full picture to hopefully get an answer on whether there is a pre-existing / standard solution that implements this.

---

### STARTING DATA — ASSUMPTIONS

Starting with a delimited data set with ***i*** sources, with each data point for each source containing ***j*** values.

Each group contains:

[image: one_in_latex] <sub>`:`</sub>
**<sub>key column</sub>**
[image: j_minus_one_in_latex] <sub>`:`</sub> **<sub>identity columns</sub>**

So assume, each row contains up to [image: i_by_j_in_latex] entries

Raw data assumptions:

- data is effective columnated
- `\n` for *row separator*
- `,` (comma) for *value separator*

Assumptions of each data set (group of ***j*** columns)

- each set of ***j*** entries is a data point for the corresponding group
- columns are contiguous within a group
- values are SORTED by the **key column**
- data sets may have different number of entries
- if across all data sets the set(s) with most values contains ***n*** values, a set with ***m*** values where ***m*** < ***n*** (a set with less values) shall contain [image: n_minus_m_in_latex] trailing blank entries in lieu of data points

Lastly assume that the ***i*** groups' key column data

- at times multiple groups will contain same key value
- within a group a specific key value may occur more than one time

---

### STARTING DATA — `EXAMPLE`

- `1st Column`: **Identity Column** - *variable name* (e.g. ***x<sub>1</sub>***,
  … ***x<sub>5</sub>***)
- `2nd Column`: **Key Column** - *% data measurement* (e.g. `1.81%`,
  … `0.66%`)

And assume initially each column group is sorted by its key column values so something like:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x<sub>1</sub> | 1.81% | x<sub>1</sub> | 1.49% | x<sub>1</sub> | 1.30% |
| x<sub>2</sub> | 1.36% | x<sub>2</sub> | 1.03% | x<sub>2</sub> | 1.07% |
| x<sub>3</sub> | 1.24% | x<sub>4</sub> | 0.93% | x<sub>4</sub> | 0.93% |
| x<sub>4</sub> | 0.82% | x<sub>3</sub> | 0.93% | x<sub>3</sub> | 0.85% |
| x<sub>5</sub> | 0.78% | x<sub>5</sub> | 0.66% | x<sub>5</sub> | 0.75% |

Or, nicely formatted in Excel, something like:

[image: individually sorted data sets]

---

### CO-SORT — PROCEDURE

So the goal is to sort the data in such a way that sorts TOGETHER all ***i*** simultaneously by the overall set of keys.  More specifically, this follows these rules:

- all groups are sorted such that the y
- each row is associated with some key value ***a*** amongst the set of all key values
- the rows are sorted on the specific key value
- for a specific row with an associated key ***a***, a data point is listed for each group if its key value matches ***a*** and it has not already been already listed above
- within a row all groups without a data point per the above rule are padded with blanks.
- if within a row (going left to right) once the first group is founded to contain a data point matching key value ***a***, if a subsequent groups has multiple not-yet-printed data points matching the key value ***a*** and one of them exactly matches the identity of the first printed group with a match, that result shall be printed on the row, otherwise the first not-yet-printed data point in the original group data matching the key value is printed.

---

### CO-SORT — `EXAMPLE (CONTINUED)`

So goal of this "co-sort" is to get to something like:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x<sub>1</sub> | 1.81% |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | x<sub>1</sub> | 1.49% |  |  |
| x<sub>2</sub> | 1.36% |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | x<sub>1</sub> | 1.30% |
| x<sub>3</sub> | 1.24% |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | x<sub>2</sub> | 1.07% |
|  |  | x<sub>2</sub> | 1.03% |  |  |
|  |  | x<sub>4</sub> | 0.93% | x<sub>4</sub> | 0.93% |
|  |  | x<sub>3</sub> | 0.93% |  |  |
| x<sub>4</sub> | 0.82% |  |  |  |  |
| x<sub>5</sub> | 0.78% |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | x<sub>5</sub> | 0.75% |

or nicely formatted in Excel:

[image: co-sort in Excel, nicely formatted]

---

### CO-SORT — IMPLEMENTATION PLAN & QUESTION

So I can obviously due this kind of sort manually via rearrangement and have done so initially.

While doing the manual edits in an Excel spreadsheet where the data is nicely formatted makes it somewhat clearer and less mistake prone than trying to do this on delimited raw text, the manual process is fairly tedious and eventually may be prone to uncaught mistake in the end result even if most are caught and fixed.

When I was doing the manual sort on 5x supersets, each containing 3 data sets for a specific thing, it was just at the edge of where this approach was still tenable.

Now I'm looking to scale up to contain an order of magnitude more supersets, and seeing I need some algorithmic approach.

Ideally I am looking for some sort of efficient method either in terminal (bash script / one-liner) or somehow using Excel (using built-ins and avoiding VBA if at all possible) to do this.

In my dream scenario there is a single built in function that does this kind of multi-group cohesive sort already in Excel, or perhaps a shell utility that when prodded with the right set of flags would also intrinsically do this kind of multi-group / multi-key value column sort.

In reality, Excel's normal ribbon access sort seems to only support sorting first on a single key column, and I haven't found any built-in function among…

[The list published by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb)

…that show much promise in doing this in one shot either (I'd guess if it existed it'd most likely be under "Logical Functions", but nothing there (including the ones clearly meant to sort) appear to be outfitted for this kind of multi-key / multi-column simultaneously sorting.

Likewise, the obvious shell equivalent (`sort` built-in) does not seem to have any flags that promise to do this in one shot either.

Currently I'm considering a BASH script / one-liner as follows:

1. Pre-sort data within groups using Excel
2. In shell read raw data and [stack key columns with print](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285774/cut-column-2-from-text-file) then use `uniq` to identify all key values in all key value columns.
3. Sort consolidated cross column key value and assign it to array. This is essentially the cross-column sorted key value without considering duplicates.
4. Create a new array to hold the final consolidated keys WITH duplicates considered.
5. To populate it, loop through consolidated, sorted cross-column key values and for
   each one loop through groups identify the maximum number the value
   occurs in any of the groups' key values and append that number of copies of the key value to the cross-column array.
6. Establish array of counters to hold the last sorted portion of each group.
7. Taking consolidated key array with duplicates, and start to loop through its values. For each group begin to loop through its values, skipping a number of data points equal to the counter for number of already sorted values in the group.  Initially this will skip no values (as counter will be initialized at zero).  Once at the the remaining set of group values loop through them.  For each entry in the raw group data array where key is greater than the current consolidated key, increment the group counter and continue. If a match is found, stop looping and add the data point to a new array (or arrays) for the group representing the co-sorted data.  If loop ends due to the group key value being small with no match found, instead insert a blank into the new array (or arrays) for the group then stop looping.
8. With all co-sorted arrays finished at the end of the loop, next loop and index by the length of the groups' co-sorted array(s) printing all group arrays such that all tab separated blanks or values across all given groups for that position are printed on a single line and printing a newline when incrementing the array index.

I also plan on explore adding indices to the original data as the product prior to printing, rather than actual data point copying.  That should be more efficient.  In parallel leveraging data containers in bash or scripting (python/perl) or compiled (C++ with stdlib) alternatives could have advantages such as (i) sorting the individual groups more efficiently initially.
(ii) Iterating on the ordered array more efficiently to provide greater efficiency in certain steps like the counting of data points matching a specific key value in a specific group or the initial individual sort of group arrays. (iii) accessing coherently in memory all values in a data point corresponding to a specific group & key common key value.

While I'm confident in the plan to code it and there seems clear optimization results down the road, it's important to note this ultimately amounts to building from scratch a fairly intuitive kind of sort that would seemingly already pre-exist.

---

### Question — Does Readily Used Solution for "Co-Sort" Already Exist? / Is Planned Implementation Re-inventing the Wheel?

While that's a clear plan towards implementation, both the base plan and the ideas to improve upon it all return me to the fundamental concern — is building this myself reinventing the wheel?

I can't shake the the feeling some simple Excel function / built-in shell utility / library has already implemented this and I'm creating unnecessary work by planning the bespoke code to implement it myself.

To put it in Excel spreadsheet function terms something like:

`sort_groups(<value set reference>, <group size in columns>, <sub-index of key value column in each group>)`

e.g. in my simple example:

`sort_groups(<cell range>, 2, 2)`

Or as a shell solution it might look something like:

`sort --method=grouped_with_multiple_key_rows --group_size=2 --key_column_relative_position=2`

This likely exists pre-built… I strong suspect.

But… does it?

Comment: I read it, but still I am not sure that is the logic that connects the input table with the output. What do you mean by this sentence. "all groups are sorted such that the y". Suggestion: try to explain the logic how you generate each row of your sample data, maybe we can understand it better. Thanks